# What's new in the next phone update?

Tags: updates, ubuntu-touch, bluetooth

Last week, there was an OTA software update for Ubuntu phone (https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/04/16/phone-updates-april/). Now I have just read (https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/04/21/ubuntu-15-04-desktop-phone-and-iot-towards-a-converged-future/?digest=true) that the new Ubuntu update 15.04 will also be delivered to the mobile device in the coming weeks.

That's great news. Can you please be more specific with regards to improvements? Will the bluetooth connectivity issue be solved? Will we be able to upload multiple photos from gallery on social media? Will the today scope sync with google? Will the phone mirror the desktop when a keyboard is plugged in?

I look forward to receiving your feedback, and keep up the good work.

Comment: I suppose, when the 15.04 update is actually ready for the phone, they'll post a list of changes at https://insights.ubuntu.com. I rather doubt simple Ubuntu users like ourselves here have any info to share.